# Google Places autocomplete closest to current location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, haml, google-places-api

I have been given some legacy code recently, where the code base has been being built for about two years now.  One of the features I will be working on is some of the Google Places stuff.  Right now in the form there is a a text field that autocompletes using the Google Places API when a user tries to put in a location.  Here is that text field:

```
%label= t(:location_label)
= text_field_tag "searching[location]",nil, :class => "tags-input location-autocomplete js-search-entity", :placeholder => "Type a venue name, street address or a city..."
```

I understand this part although I typically use ERB tags rather than HAML.

Right now, this text area appears to do the standard form of autocompletion using the Google Places API, but I am unsure exactly how this is happening as some of the code is advanced for me.  The following code I believe corresponds with the above text field:

```
initLocationField = ->
      addListing.locationField.autocomplete
        messages:
          noResults: '',
          results: ->
        source: (request, response) ->
          $.ajax
            url: "/locations"
            data:
              term: request.term
              size_type: "local"
              include_google_places: true
            success: (data) ->
              response data
```

What I would ultimately like to do is to have the auto completed responses be shown to the user based off of the closest location to their current location.  We have access to the users  IP address etc.  I see there is rank by distance documentation, but I guess my first question would be am I even looking in the right spot?

Answer (score 0):

The script you posted is CoffeeScript and it is right. You can use the user current location (from the IP if you don't have other info) to limit the result of places. Please read more at https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete